# Adjust size of child items if they overflow parent item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following simple code for a header of a website:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.navigation>ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 

  <div class="image">
   Image
  </div>
  
    <nav class="navigation"> 
      
      <ul>
        
        <li> <a> 1.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 2.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 3.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 4.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 5.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 6.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 7.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 8.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 9.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 10.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 11.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 13.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 14.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 15.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 16.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 17.0 Menu </a> </li>
        <li> <a> 18.0 Menu </a> </li>
          
      </ul>
        
    </nav>
      
</div>
```

Code can also be found in the `jsfiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zeg7pdyn/5/).

As you can see on the right side of the header the list items `<li>` are going over the edge of their parent items `ul` and `nav`.

In order to avoid this I tried to go with `overflow: hidden`. However, this solution cuts the overflowting `<li>` items on the right side but may target is that the sizes of each `<li>` item is automatically adjusted so it always fits inside the parent item.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: If the `li` won't physically fit in the space available what do you expect to happen? CSS can't detect overflow so I'm really unclear on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you want the text to shrink so it fits or do you wanted it to wrap into a new line?

Comment: @coretuer: Both options would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted your css a little to make the header height grow depending on the `li` height. Now the text inside the `li` elements wraps and fits into its parent.

A problem which still exists is, that if the contents of the `ul` are wider than your navigation div, the `li` elements will overflow the container. If it's ok for your project, you could add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `ul` so the `li` items get wrapped (I've added that bit too, just remove the comment to see its effect).

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  /* height: 10%; */
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #ff0
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: aqua
}

.navigation>ul {
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue
}

.navigation>ul>li {
  /* width: 100%; */
  flex: 1 0 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 

  <div class="image">
   Image
  </div>
  
<nav class="navigation"> 
  
  <ul>
    
    <li> <a> 1.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 2.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 3.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 4.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 5.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 6.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 7.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 8.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 9.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 10.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 11.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 13.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 14.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 15.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 16.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 17.0 Menu </a> </li>
    <li> <a> 18.0 Menu </a> </li>
      
  </ul>
    
</nav>
  
</div>
```

### EDIT

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hdkakf) with two possiblities:

- the navigation stays within one line, everything that overflows the container is hidden but you can scroll on the x-axis
- the `li` elements are wrapped so all elements are visible